# Spark local support Fair schedule module, but only one stage is active and others are pending

Tags: apache-spark

According the document from spark official, I set the default pool and a customer pool as `FAIR`. And I am sure it works by the spark UI.

But there is only one stage is active. Anyone knows what's wrong about it?

here is the pool configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
  <pool name="production">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
  </pool>
  <pool name="test">
    <schedulingMode>FIFO</schedulingMode>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <minShare>1</minShare>
  </pool>
</allocations>
```

And I am sure I have commited the jobs to serveral FAIR pool.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77085650/edit) your question and share which steps you took to get to where you are. What configurations did you set, how did you configure your pools, what code are you running, ...

Comment: Can you share more details around what action you are calling and what is the resultant DAG ? Also what is your machine configuration ?

Comment: Sorry @koedel here is the pool configuration. <?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
  <pool name="production">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
  </pool>
  <pool name="test">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <minShare>3</minShare>
  </pool>
</allocations> and I set the  conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")